# Pulling a specific User group - Powershell

Tags: microsoft-excel, powershell, active-directory

So I currently have a script that imports samaccountnames from a csv and gets Name, samaccountname, user group, and the group description.  Outputs each in an individual line.  the script below:

````
```
Import-Csv -Path .\users.csv | ForEach-Object{

$user = get-aduser -Identity $_.samaccountname -Properties name, 
samaccountname, memberof

$(
if ($user.memberof.count -gt 1) {
    foreach ($group in $user.MemberOf) {
        $user | select name, samaccountname, @{n='group';e={$group -replace '^CN=(?<Name>.*?),(?:OU|CN).*$', '${Name}' -join ', '}}, @{n='GroupDescription';e={(Get-ADGroup $group -Properties description).description}}
    }
} elseif ($user.MemberOf.Count -eq 1) {
    $user | select name, samaccountname, @{n='group';e={$_.memberof  | select 
-f 1}}, @{n='GroupDescription';e={(Get-ADGroup $group -Properties 
 description).description}}
} else {
    $user | select name, samaccountname, @{n='group';e={$_.memberof }}, 
@{n='GroupDescription';e={''}}
}
)
  }| Export-Csv -path '' -NoTypeInformation
````

The one thing that I need to accomplish is for each user check if they are a member of a specific group and if they are pull that out into its own column in the CSV.  It can be a wildcard, for example if the group is "this-*" it would get split off into its own column.

Any ideas?

------------EDIT------EDIT------EDIT-------------------

I have added this

```
@{n='CertifyingGroup';e={($_.memberof -like “*org-*”)}}
```

Which outputs into the CSV LDAP/Distinguished name of the group but when I add the replace function I am using already in the script to remove that nonsense to make it readable it only returns true or false

Comment: What should be in the seperate group column if the User is a member of the "this-*" group?

Comment: Just the group name.  So when the value is currently stored in the $user.memberof variable it is in LDAP format.  Which is why the current line removes that mumbo jumbo and leaves the group name.  But for what ever reason I cant pull any group names out of that ....at all

So yea the separate column should just have the group name that matches

Comment: See Edit in original post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers - Any update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your requirements correctly this should do what you need.

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path .\users.csv
#CertifyingGroup Lookup
$certifyingGroupQuerty = "Domain*"
$groupReport = foreach ($user in $users) {
    $userAD = Get-ADUser -Identity $user.SamAccountName -Properties MemberOf
    foreach ($groupDN in $userAD.MemberOf) {
        $groupAD = Get-ADGroup -Identity $groupDN -Properties Description
        $certifyingGroup = if ($groupAD.Name -like $certifyingGroupQuerty) { $groupAD.Name }
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            "UserName"           = $userAD.Name
            "UserSamAccountName" = $userAD.SamAccountName
            "GroupName"          = $groupAD.Name
            "GroupDescription"   = $groupAD.Description
            "CertifyingGroup"    = $certifyingGroup
        }
    }
}
$groupReport | Export-Csv -Path C:\GroupReport.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Hope it helps?